# Why should I use {{#link-to}} instead of <a></a> in EmberJS?

Tags: ember.js

This is a pretty newbie question. However, in EmberJS, I've found that both of the methods work for linking to the blog page in my application.

```
<p>{{#link-to 'posts'}} See my blog{{/link-to}}</p>
<a href="posts"> See my blog</a>
```

Is it better to use {{link-to}} in EmberJS? How come?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The difference is that the `{{link-to}}` component will navigate to the specified route within the current running Ember application, while `<a href="posts">` will do a new browser request to that location and re-start your Ember app at that route. You should use `{{link-to}}` since you'll be using the Ember internals to navigate within your single-page application and it will be a smoother user experience.

While they both *can* work, watch your browser closely and you'll see the anchor tag will give you a page refresh and re-launch your Ember app (though in the right location). Using a `{{link-to}}` will feel faster since Ember is presenting the new page via javascript rather than restarting after a page refresh. It's the difference between navigating *within* a single-page application, and jumping into a SPA from an external page.

While Ember does render an anchor tag in place of the `{{link-to}}` at run-time, it interjects to stop the default anchor tag behaviour. The docs explain it like so:

> By default the `{{link-to}}` component prevents the default browser
>   action by calling `preventDefault()` as this sort of action bubbling is
>   normally handled internally and we do not want to take the browser to
>   a new URL (for example).

(from https://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Templates.helpers.html#toc_allowing-default-action)

Also, with the `{{link-to}}` component you can pass a model directly into the route. This is a bit more advanced, but the Ember guides have some good examples. 
https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.13.0/templates/links/